# My access token in dev role for Facebook API is missing validation after I login with Facebook again

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I generate an access token in the developer ro ok token debug request.

When I reload the page after changing the developer access token in VSCode it works, but when I do it again with Facebook another token is generated and my developer access token is "lost".

```json
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application
```

**I tried to debug the token in he Facebook tool, but this error still persists.** I don't know what it means:

[image]